# call services of that page , if (mobile app) net online angularjs + cordova (android and IOS)

Tags: angularjs, cordova

If mobile data is on, I want to reload the current page, how do I know that the net is on.

added below code `deviceready` event

```
document.addEventListener("online", function toggleCon(e, $route) {
    if (e.type == "offline") {
        navigator.notification.alert("Sorry, you are offline.", function() {}, "Offline!");
    } else {
        //  navigator.notification.alert("Woot, you are back online.", function () { }, "Online!");
        $route.reload();
    }
}, false);
```

It's working once the device is ready, what if the connection lost in between.

I want to reload current page services ,is there is a way to identify that.

Answer (score 0):

`online` event will be called every time your app got back online.

`deviceready` event is fired when you app is loaded. `online` event is registered after that.

if your app lost connection after that and came back online that event and its callback will always be called.

Comment: in every page we had no of services , i am checking navigator.connection.type and showing alert message if type is none . i want to run all those services of current controller ,while coming online .is there a way to identify in that service or controller